# Solr search by result of division of two fields

Tags: search, solr

is it possible to search in Solr by a result of a mathematical function between values stored in two fields?

For example:

```
?fq=FIELDA:{!func}div(FIELDA, FIELDB)
```

or:

```
?fq=FIELDA:[* TO 100/FIELDB]
```

I appreciate greatly your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You may use [**Frange**](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_1/solr-core/org/apache/solr/search/FunctionRangeQParserPlugin.html) query

For example:  (note: the idea is to show an example rather than provide a well thought formula)

```
fq={!frange l=0 u=0} sub(div(FIELDA, FIELDB),FIELDA)

q={!frange l=10 u=10} div(FIELDA,1) # this will search for 10 in FIELDA
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I started with the first example, using `q=FIELDA:{!func}div(10, 2)` and received error `org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Expected identifier at pos 7 str='div(10,'`. Cannot figure it out what could be missing...

Comment: Could you post the complete URL and solr version?

Comment: Hi, it's my bad to show the first q example. I have modified the answer, and please use frange instead. things like "q={!frange l=10 u=10} div(FIELDA,1)" should work.

Comment: Your "fq" example worked like a charm, although I used only `fq={!frange l=0 u=0}div(FIELDA, FIELDB)` (without the "sub()" part) in my case. Hopefully will not do any harm to Solr :) Thank you again for your help!

Comment: My pleasure! Right, as long as you can come up with an equation that does the calculation right to fit the frange query.